# Função para somar elementos de um vetor não retorna valor correto

Tags: c, ponteiro

Estou fazendo um programa para uma lista de compras, o usuário passa ao programa os valores de cada produto e cada um é armazenado num vetor.
Depois somo os elementos do vetor para dar o valor total da compra, diante disso criei uma função:

```
float valor(float *k, int *t){
int i;
float soma = 0;
for(i = 0; i<*t; i++){
    soma += k[i];
   }
return(soma);
}
```

E no `main`, faço a chamada do programa;

```
teste = valor(&vTotal, &quant);
printf("Valor total: %f", teste);
```

O argumento `vTotal` é o vetor onde estão os valores de cada produto dado pelo usuário e quant é a quantidade de itens do vetor.

O `printf` está mostra 0.00000 na tela, já *printei* o valor do vetor diretamente na tela e esta sendo alocado corretamente no vetor, mas não sei porquê a soma está zerando.

Exemplo completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ghe.h"

int main()
{
float *vTotal;
int quant;
int i;
int teste = 0;

printf("Digite a quantidade: ");
scanf("%d", &quant);

vTotal = aloca(&quant);

for(i = 0; i<quant; i++){
    printf("Digite o valor %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%f", &vTotal[i]);
}
    teste = valor(&vTotal, &quant);
    printf("\n %.2f", teste);
    free(vTotal);
}
```

"ghe.h"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float *aloca(int *num);
float valor(float *k, int *t);

float valor(float *k, int *t){
int i;
float soma = 0;
for(i = 0; i<*t; i++){
soma += k[i];
   }
return(soma);
}

float *aloca(int *num){
float *u;
u = malloc(*(num)*sizeof(float));
return(u);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O código tinha vários problemas, até para compilar tive que mexer em muita coisa. Acabei chegando no resultado final que funcionou. Não sei dizer o que era o problema relatado na pergunta, em tese eu não mudei lógica alguma, só consertei o que impedia a compilação. Há uma chance de haver um conflito com a função `aloca()` que existe no C. Fiz de uma forma que considero mais simples e organizado tentando manter a intenção.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float valor(float *k, int t){
    float soma = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++){
        soma += k[i];
    }
    return soma;
}

int main() {
    int quant;
    printf("Digite a quantidade: ");
    scanf("%d", &quant);
    float *vTotal = malloc(quant * sizeof(float));
    for(int i = 0; i < quant; i++){
        printf("Digite o valor %d: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &vTotal[i]);
    }
    float teste = valor(vTotal, quant);
    printf("\n %.2f", teste);
    free(vTotal);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/l30xX8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/neathuml-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/SumArray.c).

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. Eu estou começando agora com alocação dinâmica e ainda estou meio perdido com ponteiros, valeu mesmo. Só uma dúvida.
Pra funções que eu declaro um dos argumentos como um ponteiro, não é necessário o uso do &? Depois dessa tua resposta, percebi que quando faço o valor(&vTotal, &quant), dá zero, mas quando tiro os &, a função retorna o valor correto

Comment: Quando o parâmetro espera um ponteiro e o argumento passado já é um ponteiro não pode usar o operador `&` para passar. O segundo eu tirei porque não precisa ser um ponteiro pra nada.